# How to check user input in combobox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, sqldatareader

I have a ComboBox that populate from class named class1
then i created object named obj from the class,
i use SqlDataReader

```
combobox1.DataSource = obj.Myfunction();
combobox1.ValueMember = "ID";
combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

and the user can also write in the ComboBox
i want to check if the user input are in the ComboBox items

```
if( comboBox1.Items.Contains(comboBox1.Text) )
   //do something
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("The comboBox1 contains new value");
}
```

but the result false

i don't want to use another method like SqlDataAdapter

thanks advanced

UPDATE

As temporary solution I used this code

```
int m = combobox1.SelectedIndex;
if (((class1)combobox1.Items[m]).Name.ToString() == combobox1.Text)
{
}
else
{
 MessageBox.Show("The comboBox1 contains new value");
}
```

thank you again

Comment: if result is `false`, it means user input does not exists in Items list. Have you checked for case sensitiveness or space characters?

Comment: Please give us more details.

Comment: the user enter for example "item1" to the combobox then the user click the button that contain the if condition

Answer (score 1):

My Solution is little bit lengthy, but this will solve your problem

```
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string value = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.Items[i]);
            if (value.Contains(comboBox1.Text))
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (count > 0)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The comboBox1 contains new value");
        }
```

This code is very simple and easy to understand, But you can use LINQ to shorten your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but I suppose the data returned from

```
obj.Myfunction();
```

(what you're setting as data source) is not a `List<string>` and thus, when checking if the inner collection of the combobox contains a `string` (returned from `comboBox1.Text`), it doesn't contain a string but an object.
Since those two are always different (`object` and `string`), it is always false.

Have you tried setting your data source to a list of strings?

Comment: I'm sorry for commenting in the wrong place.
@Jalal Adding comments anywhere except ones own questions and answers is not possible with a reputation score of 49 or lower. Which is why I have to comment here :(

Answer (score 0):

Items is an ItemCollection and not list of strings. In your case its a collection of ComboboxItem and you need to check its Content property.

```
comboboxId.Items.Cast<ComboBoxItem>().Any(com=> com.Content.Equals("Your string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using List of your class type to bind to combo.

You should validate against the source of the combo box like -

```
        List<ClassType> cboSource = comboBox1.DataSource as List<ClassType>;
        var itemAlreadyThere = cboSource.Any(a => a.Name == comboBox1.Text);

        if (itemAlreadyThere)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The comboBox1 contains old value");
        }
        //do something
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The comboBox1 contains new value");
        }
```

> As a suggestion, instead of casting the combo data source, use a
>   private variable, populate it, and use it for both binding to combo
>   and for validation

Answer (score 0):

I had this type of behaviour a couple of months ago.

I filled a combobox with class data

```
class MyValue
{
  public string ID { get; set; }
  public string prop1 { get; set; }
  public string prop2 { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }

  public static List<MyValue> Get()
  { 
    //create a list of MyValues and return it
    return new List<MyValue>();
  }
}
```

in the GUI:

```
mycombo.ValueMember = "ID";
mycombo.DisplayMember = "prop1";
mycombo.DataSource = MyValue.Get();
```

afterwards I had the selectedvalue as a property:

```
public MyValue SelectedValue
{
  get
  {
    if(mycombo.SelectedValue is MyValue)
      return (MyValue)mycombo.SelectedValue);
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} as new value", mycombo.SelectedText));
      return new MyValue{prop1 = mycombo.SelectedText};
    }
  }
}
```